# Brainfuck interpreter in C++ produces incorrect result

Tags: c++, for-loop, interpreter, brainfuck

I'm writing a Brainfuck interpreter in C++ and I'm having trouble getting this to work correctly. I'm new to C++, but I know JavaScript, which is why I'm writing this interpreter using my JavaScript code (which works perfectly) for reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
void printVec(vector<int> arr) {
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i ++) {
    cout << arr[i] << ", " << endl;
  }
}
vector<int> brain(string code, string input = "") {
  vector<int> tape(1);
  vector<string> stack(0);
  int cur = 0;
  int mem = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < code.length(); i ++) {
    switch (code[i]) {
      case '+':
        tape[cur]++;
        tape[cur] %= 256;
        break;
      case '-':
        tape[cur]--;
        if (tape[cur] < 0) tape[cur] = 256 - tape[cur] * -1;
        break;
      case '>':
        cur++;
        try {
          tape.at(cur);
        } catch (out_of_range& oor) {
          tape.push_back(0);
        }
        break;
      case '<':
        cur--;
        if (cur < 0) {
          cout << "Index too low!" << endl;
          throw 1;
        }
      case '[':
        mem = i;
        break;
      case ']':
        if (tape[cur] > 0) i = mem;
        break;
    }
  }
  return tape;
}
int main() {
  printVec(brain("+++[>++<-]"));
  return 0;
}
```

This produces 0, 2 as the output, when it should be 0, 6. I think the problem is with the way I handle Brainfuck loops (cases '[' and ']') but I can't figure out the exact issue. In JavaScript, the code for these cases looks almost exactly the same, but it works fine.

Any help will be appreciated, including any tips on how to write other parts of this code better.

Comment: look at case '<', and see if its missing something. also you shouldn't use exceptions for flow control.

Comment: I suggest you learn C++ first, ignoring your javascript knowledge.

Comment: @juanchopanza do you mean taking a class? This is the way I have learned languages in the past (trial and error).

Comment: Thank you. After adding the break statement the problem is solved. @M.Aroosi

Answer (score 1):

Your `case '<':` is missing a `break` and thus will *fallthrough* and perform the function of `case '['` as well.  Add the missing `break;` and see if that is your only issue.

```
  case '<':
    cur--;
    if (cur < 0) {
      cout << "Index too low!" << endl;
      throw 1;
    }
    break;        // Add this
  case '[':
    mem = i;
    break;
```